# How to pass in a variable from middleware to controller in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, php-carbon

I made a input with type time and when i select 12 pm it shows me `12:00` but when i try to use carbon and get time for 12:00 like this -> `Carbon::now()->addMinute(30)->format('H:i')` It shows me `00:00` so what can i do about that? how can i make them both the same way?

My html code ->

```html
<input type="time">
```

My php code ->

```js
return Carbon::now()->addMinute(30)->format('H:i'); // Added 30 because 30 minutes was left for 12:00 pm
```

Comment: Could you add your middleware/controller logic that uses the input?

Comment: If you want 01-12 instead of 00-23, use lower `h` instead of upper `H` as per the doc (https://www.php.net/manual/fr/datetime.format.php)